# Help proving $\phi$ is a homomorphism when given $\to a - (c/2)i$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Ok, so I think I understand how to find a homomorphism and I get the concept that it is a mapping of the same structure but I’m confused by the $a - (c/2)i$ part of this question?[image: see image]

I’m confused because if $f(xy)$ needs to equal $f(x) + f(y)$ then how do we do that with $a - (c/2)i$ ?

*also, does the x and y used above represent the G matrix and a - (c/2)i respectively? Or do they represent something by else?

In which case, how would I multiply the G matrix by a - (c/2)i and also add them?

Here's what I have done
[image: Here's what I have done]

Comment: What are you confused about?  $a - \frac{c}{2}i$ is a perfectly defined complex number.

Comment: It’s in the attached image as I don’t know how to use MathJax

Comment: Have you tried multiplying two matrices of that given form? What happens to the entries on the upper diagonal?

Comment: Yes, but I don’t understand what we have to do with the a - (c/2)i? Do we make it equal to 0 as that’s the identity element and then what?

Comment: Compute $xy$, apply $f$.  Next apply $f$ and get $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ and add them.  Show the results are equal.

Comment: Do x and y represent the G matrix and a - (c/2)i respectively? Or do they represent something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help proving that this is a Homomorphism...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4128000/help-proving-that-this-is-a-homomorphism)

Comment: @user1729 It's the other way round: Both questions are by the same users and the newer one should be closed as a duplicate of this.

Comment: @Christoph Sure, but the user is currently interacting with the other one, and has made more effort on it.

Comment: Note that the $-\frac 12$ factor on $c$ in the complex domain is arbitrary; the homomorphism works for any fixed  multipliers $s,t$ in $sa+tci$.

Comment: In your working image: what is the value of the complex number  $\phi(x)$? What is the value of $\phi(y)$?

Answer (score 1):

Given $x,y\in G$, we know these are matrices of the form
$$
x = \begin{pmatrix} 1&a&b\\&1&c\\&&1\end{pmatrix},\ 
y = \begin{pmatrix} 1&a'&b'\\&1&c'\\&&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
for some $a,b,c,a',b',c'\in\mathbb R$.

Computing $\phi(xy)$, we get

\begin{align*}
\phi(xy) &= \phi\left( \begin{pmatrix} 1&a+a'&b+b'+ac'\\&1&c+c'\\&&1\end{pmatrix}\right) \\
&= (a+a')-\frac{c+c'}{2}\mathrm i \\
&= \left( a-\frac c 2 \mathrm i\right) + \left(a'-\frac {c'} 2 \mathrm i\right) \\
&= \phi(x) + \phi(y).
\end{align*}